# Create multiple labels on fly in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to create multiple labels on fly based on the number entered by user. For example if user writes 10 in textbox, 10 labels should be created with id label1 - label10 and i want to put separate text in those labels. Any idea how to do it in asp.net with c# sharp code ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like the following should get you started.

```
// get user input count from the textbxo
string countString = MyTextBox.Text;
int count = 0;

// attempt to convert to a number
if (int.TryParse(countString, out count))
{
    // you would probably also want to validate the number is
    // in some range, like 1 to 100 or something to avoid
    // DDOS attack by entering a huge number.

    // create as many labels as number user entered
    for (int i = 1; i <= count; i++)
    {
        // setup label and add them to the page hierarchy
        Label lbl = new Label();
        lbl.ID = "label" + i;
        lbl.Text = "The Label Text.";
        MyParentControl.Controls.Add(lbl);
    }
}
else
{
    // if user did not enter valid number, show error message
    MyLoggingOutput.Text = "Invalid number: '" + countString + "'.";
}
```

Of course, you would need to correct:

1. What your actual textbox is, for `MyTextBox`
2. What text you have in your labels.
3. What parent control `MyParentControl` for adding the labels to the page.
4. What to do when the number is invalid, i.e., `MyLoggingOutput`.
5. Proper validation, i.e., don't allow user to enter number > 100 or < 1, for example.  You could handle with custom code or with validation controls, such as `RangeValidator` and `CompareValidator`.

Comment: But this creates a span in the browser with id=label1-10. Now my question is how do I access span in c# code behind to change its text ?

Comment: A note about dynamic controls (which is why they are generally to be avoided unless absolutely necessary).  If you want to access them in the code-behind in a later post-back, you have to re-create all of the labels *on every postback* (i.e., literally run the above code every single time in `Page_Load`).  Once you have done this, you should be able to access them with `FindControl` as @Shyju mentions in comments below.

Answer (score 0):

Read the textbox value and do loop inside which you create an object of label control and set the ID and text property values

```
int counter = Convert.ToInt32(txtCounter.Text);
for(int i=1;i<=counter;i++)
{
   Label objLabel = new Label();
   objLabel.ID="label"+i.ToString();
   objLabel.Text="I am number "+i.ToString();

   //Control is ready.Now let's add it to the form 
   form1.Controls.Add(objLabel);
}
```

Assuming `txtCounter` is the TextBox control where user enters the number of labels to be created and form1 is a form in your page with a runat="server" attribute.

Comment: But this creates a span in the browser with id=label1-10. My question is how do I access span in c# code behind to change its text ?

Comment: In the original question you were asking how to create 10 labels with different text. It is always a better practice to be more specific about your question.

Comment: I run your code but when I inspected element in the browser it creates 10 span with id label1-10. Is there anyway I can access these spans in code behind and change their text ?

Comment: @A.J Use the findcontrol method.

Comment: I did it like this HtmlGenericControl spanp = (HtmlGenericControl)(form1.FindControl(variable3)); but its giving an error System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object when i access spanp.InnerHtml

Comment: `Label label2 = (Label) form1.FindControl("label1");` should work