# How can I set ASP element ID dynamically in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net

As you can see below, I have a loop where I create some ASP label's.

```
function func(val) {
    var mod = Math.ceil(val / 9);
    for (var i = 0; i < mod; i++) {
        html = '<div class="carousel-item">
                  <table>
                    <tr>
                      <td>Temp ' + parseInt(i * 9 + 1) + '</td>
                      <td>Temp  ' + parseInt(i * 9 + 2) + '</td>
                      <td>Temp  ' + parseInt(i * 9 + 3) + '</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <td><asp:Label ID="TempCL1" runat="server" Text="xxx"></asp:Label></td>
                      <td><asp:Label ID="TempCL2" runat="server" Text="xxx"></asp:Label></td>
                      <td><asp:Label ID="TempCL3" runat="server" Text="xxx"></asp:Label></td>
                    </tr>
                  </table>
                </div>';

              $(".carousel-inner").html($(".carousel-inner").html() + html);
        }
    }
```

My code works fine, but I need to modify the Label ID's. For example:
From

```
'<tr><td class="Valorppal"><asp:Label ID="TempCL1" runat="server" Text="xxx"></asp:Label></td>'
```

To something like

```
'<tr><td class="Valorppal"><asp:Label ID="TempCL' + parseInt(i * 9 + 1) + '" runat="server" Text="xxx"></asp:Label></td>'
```

But I got an error ("TempCL' + parseInt(i * 9 + 1) + '" is not a valid identifier.)

Comment: Beware: You are trying to generate `<asp:Label ID="..." runat="server"`> tags **inside the browser**, but that will never work: tags with `runat="server"` will only do what you want if they are **created or generated from inside your server-side ASP.NET code**, because only then IIS and .NET can execute them for you. A browser simply has no idea what `<asp:Label>` is.

Comment: @PeterB Hmm..But my firt piece of code works anyways... I understand...So what should I do to get what I want?

Comment: For a start see this: [Create multiple labels on fly in asp.net](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10693904/1220550). More in general, you might benefit from looking at a couple of ASP.NET WebForms tutorials (e.g. search for it on YouTube or Microsoft Virtual Academy).

Comment: But I can't do it from server side... I need it from Javascript. I tried using replace function to replace the ID string but neither does it work

Comment: You cannot set a Server Control ID with javascript. You will have to create them dynamically as @PeterB says. But your question sounds like an [X-Y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: Please see my answer. It is not yet a functioning carousel, but at least the issues in it were solved.

Comment: You cannot create an ASP.Net element in Javascript.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you have no real reason to use `<asp:Label>`, so I replaced them with `<span>` tags.

Also I added `\` at the end of every line for the long html string, which is needed to create multi-line string literals in Javascript with regular quotes as delimiters.

Finally I used jQuery `.append()` which does what you did, while being a lot more readable.

Working code, at least for the parts that you gave:

```js
function func(val) {
    var mod = Math.ceil(val / 9);
    for (var i = 0; i < mod; i++) {
        var html =
'<div class="carousel-item">\
  <table>\
    <tr>\
      <td>Temp ' + (i * 9 + 1) + '</td>\
      <td>Temp ' + (i * 9 + 2) + '</td>\
      <td>Temp ' + (i * 9 + 3) + '</td>\
    </tr>\
    <tr>\
      <td><span id="TempCL' + (i * 9 + 1) + '">xxx</span></td>\
      <td><span id="TempCL' + (i * 9 + 2) + '">xxx</span></td>\
      <td><span id="TempCL' + (i * 9 + 3) + '">xxx</span></td>\
    </tr>\
  </table>\
</div>';
        $(".carousel-inner").append(html);
    }
}

func(23);
```

```css
td { border: solid 1px green; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="carousel-inner"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I need asp:Label tags cause I have to set values every 10 seconds on server side (reading some files).

Comment: Why? I want to set asp:Label's values on server side (using FindControl), but I want to create them from javascript side.

Comment: You can't. Because you can't. There is no need arguing what you want, if what you want is impossible. Client-side can never generate server-side objects, in any framework, ever.

Comment: Why not? I generated them with my first piece of code like I said you. TempCL1, TempCL2 and TempCL3 were generated correctly and I could assign values to them

Comment: @DanielR Peter is 100% correct.  You **cannot** create server-side elements inside the browser.  If you want to add elements that interact with the server-side code (using standard postback) then server-side code **must** create them.

Comment: Archer, I did it. By the way I understand that could be insecure.

Answer (score -2):

Please make id of asp:label dynamic too as follows:-

```
<asp:Label ID="TempCL'+parseInt(i * 9 + 2)+'" runat="server" Text="xxx"></asp:Label>
```

Hope it works!

Comment: That's what I did but I got the error I wrote. :(. Remember this code is inside apostrophe (')